# SQL Selecting Values From Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, join, datatables

I have a table called SLA_BUSINESS_FACING_SLA where each unique row contains ID's for certain attributes. They're called ASV_ID, Process_ID, SLA_Comp_ID, and SLA_Type_ID (the Columns). I have 4 other tables that I need to pull names from using the ID's from the SLA_BUSINESS table. I have two variables that hold ASV_ID and Process_ID and need to find all rows in SLA_BUSINESS where the ASV_ID and Process_ID's match. Then once I find all matching rows, take the ID's and get the actaul names, using the other 4 tables. I am not experienced in SQL, and finding a good solution to this is confusing me. I do have code that is working however I am sure it is not efficient:

```
(SELECT (SELECT component_class FROM SLA_COMP_CLASS WHERE 
BUSINESS_FACING_SLA.SLA_Comp_ID = SLA_COMP_CLASS.SLA_Comp_ID) AS        Component_Class,
(SELECT CommonName FROM vkd593_COAF_ASVs WHERE 
BUSINESS_FACING_SLA.ASV_ID = ASVs.Name) AS ASV,
(SELECT process_name FROM PROCESSES WHERE 
BUSINESS_FACING_SLA.PROCESS_ID = PROCESSES.decomp_num) AS Process,
(SELECT component_type FROM SLA_COMP_TYPE WHERE 
BUSINESS_FACING_SLA.SLA_Type_ID = SLA_COMP_TYPE.SLA_Type_ID) AS  Component_Type
FROM BUSINESS_FACING_SLA
WHERE ASV_ID = 'Blah' AND PROCESS_ID = 'Blah')
```

Any methods for a faster, most efficient query? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query would normally be as fast as doing `left outer join`s (the alternative and more traditional method.

The key is to ensure that all the columns in the reference tables are indexed (it the column in the `where` clause is the primary keys, then this happens automatically).  Actually, the best indexes would have both columns mentioned:

```
SLA_COMP_CLASS(SLA_Comp_ID, component_class)
vkd593_COAF_ASVs(Name, CommonName)
PROCESSES(decomp_num, process_name)
SLA_COMP_TYPE(SLA_Type_ID, component_type)
```

These are called "covering indexes" because all the columns needed for the query are in the index, so the engine does not have to look up columns in the data pages.

Your outer query can also benefit from an index:

```
BUSINESS_FACING_SLA(ASV_ID, blah_id)
```

Comment: Ah I see. This is helpful, thank you. So the nested SELECT's (if columns indexed correctly) would be about the same speed as joins?

Comment: @Cassus . . . Both query plans would normally use the index to look up the values.  The `left join` method can pull multiple columns from the subtables, but it runs the risk of generating multiple rows, if a reference table has duplicates.  On the other hand, the nested query method runs the risk of failing when there are duplicates.  But on any reasonable database, the two should have very similar performance.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the `JOIN` keyword - using a LEFT (or INNER) JOIN could potentially improve your performance, and definitely simplify your query.

```
SELECT 
    SAL_COMP_CLASS.Component_Class,
    vkd593_COAF_ASVs.CommonName AS ASV,
    PROCESSES.Process_Name AS Process,
    SLA_COMP_TYPE.Component_Type 
FROM 
    BUSINESS_FACING_SLA
     LEFT JOIN 
    SLA_COMP_CLASS ON BUSINESS_FACING_SLA.SLA_Comp_ID = SLA_COMP_CLASS.SLA_Comp_ID
     LEFT JOIN 
    vkd593_COAF_ASVs ON BUSINESS_FACING_SLA.ASV_ID = ASVs.Name
     LEFT JOIN 
    PROCESSES ON BUSINESS_FACING_SLA.PROCESS_ID = PROCESSES.decomp_num
     LEFT JOIN 
    SLA_COMP_TYPE ON BUSINESS_FACING_SLA.SLA_Type_ID = SLA_COMP_TYPE.SLA_Type_ID
WHERE ASV_ID = 'Blah' AND PROCESS_ID = 'Blah'
```